# Замена одного блока другим

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Здравствуйте у меня следующая проблема:
Есть блок внутри которого 2 других блока.[image: Блок]

Слева ссылки при нажатии на которые выходит информация справа. Так вот надо сделать так чтобы при нажатии на эти ссылки информация справа менялась. Например нажимаю на "главный экран" Справа информация как на скрине , при нажатии на "Изображения" та информация которая была скрывается и появляется другая информация. Надеюсь суть понятна , очень нуждаюсь в помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let main= document.getElementById('main'); определяем кнопку "Главный экран"
let image= document.getElementById('image'); определяем кнопку "Изображения"

main.onclick = function() {
    main.style.display = "block"; показываем главную вкладку справа
    image.style.display = "none"; скрываем вкладку изображения
}
```

Ну и так повторить со всеми

Comment: А если получать не через id, a `querySelectorAll('.className');` и прописать click в цикле?) Чтобы любое количество элементов свободно переключалось.